# Oracle SQL Joining two separate user generated tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, union

I have a query that shows the amount of empty locations based on the name of the location, what I am trying to add is the total locations column I have created next to the empty locations, then I was going to do math to display the percentage of available inventory space. I'm fairly new to subqueries and such, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong

Full Query:

```
select bin_type_name, floor, empty_locations, total day, time from(
    (select bin_type_name,
    bin_level as floor, 
    sum(bin) as empty_locations,
    to_char(sysdate, 'MM-DD-YYYY ') as day,
    to_char(sysdate,'hh:mi:ssam') as time
    from
    (select count(bins.bin_id) as bin, bin_type_name, bin_level
      from bins
      left join bin_items bi on bi.bin_id = bins.bin_id
      where bi.quantity is null
      and usage = '1024'
      group by bins.bin_id, bin_level, bin_type_name)
      group by bin_type_name, bin_level, to_char(sysdate, 'MM-DD-YYYY '), to_char(sysdate,'hh:mi:ssam')
      )order by bin_level) a
      inner join a on a.bin_type_name = b.bin_type_name
    union
    (select bin_type_name, count(bin_type_name) as total, bin_level from bins
    where usage = '1024'
    group by bin_type_name, bin_level
    )order by floor) b;
```

Top portion:

```
    select bin_type_name, count(b.bin_id) empty_locations, bin_level from bins b
left join bin_items bi on bi.bin_id = b.bin_id
where quantity is null
and usage = '1024'
group by bin_type_name, bin_level, quantity
order by bin_level;
```

Top Result:

```
14-KIVA-DEEP    1   645 12-30-2013  04:35:47pm
18-KIVA-DEEP    1   235 12-30-2013  04:35:47pm
24-KIVA-DEEP    1   74  12-30-2013  04:35:47pm
30-KIVA-DEEP    1   35  12-30-2013  04:35:47pm
34-KIVA-DEEP    1   116 12-30-2013  04:35:47pm
48-KIVA-DEEP    1   17  12-30-2013  04:35:47pm
78-KIVA-TALL    1   154 12-30-2013  04:35:47pm
PALLET-SINGLE   1   654 12-30-2013  04:35:47pm
14-KIVA-DEEP    2   783 12-30-2013  04:35:47pm
18-KIVA-DEEP    2   847 12-30-2013  04:35:47pm
24-KIVA-DEEP    2   120 12-30-2013  04:35:47pm
30-KIVA-DEEP    2   276 12-30-2013  04:35:47pm
34-KIVA-DEEP    2   32  12-30-2013  04:35:47pm
PALLET-SINGLE   2   526 12-30-2013  04:35:47pm
```

Bottom Portion

```
   select bin_type_name, bin_level, count(bin_type_name) as total from bins
```

where usage = '1024'
group by bin_type_name, bin_level
order by bin_level;

Bottom Result

```
14-KIVA-DEEP    1   8381
18-KIVA-DEEP    1   6004
24-KIVA-DEEP    1   12331
30-KIVA-DEEP    1   4607
34-KIVA-DEEP    1   4771
48-KIVA-DEEP    1   4800
48-KIVA-XL          1   2698
78-KIVA-TALL    1   3200
PALLET-SINGLE   1   3202
14-KIVA-DEEP    2   4219
18-KIVA-DEEP    2   8502
24-KIVA-DEEP    2   8773
30-KIVA-DEEP    2   6997
34-KIVA-DEEP    2   829
PALLET-SINGLE   2   2848
```

**Desired Result:**

```
bin_type_name   floor   empty   % available total   day time
14-KIVA-DEEP    1   645 7.70%   8381    12/30/2013  04:38:12pm
18-KIVA-DEEP    1   234 3.90%   6004    12/30/2013  04:38:12pm
24-KIVA-DEEP    1   74  0.60%   12331   12/30/2013  04:38:12pm
30-KIVA-DEEP    1   35  0.76%   4607    12/30/2013  04:38:12pm
34-KIVA-DEEP    1   116 2.43%   4771    12/30/2013  04:38:12pm
48-KIVA-DEEP    1   17  0.35%   4800    12/30/2013  04:38:12pm
48-KIVA-XL          1   0   0.00%   2698    12/30/2013  04:38:12pm
78-KIVA-TALL    1   154 4.81%   3200    12/30/2013  04:38:12pm
PALLET-SINGLE   1   654 20.42%  3202    12/30/2013  04:38:12pm
14-KIVA-DEEP    2   783 18.56%  4219    12/30/2013  04:38:12pm
18-KIVA-DEEP    2   847 9.96%   8502    12/30/2013  04:38:12pm
24-KIVA-DEEP    2   120 1.37%   8773    12/30/2013  04:38:12pm
30-KIVA-DEEP    2   276 3.94%   6997    12/30/2013  04:38:12pm
34-KIVA-DEEP    2   32  3.86%   829 12/30/2013  04:38:12pm
PALLET-SINGLE   2   524 18.40%  2848    12/30/2013  04:38:12pm
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong?

Comment: I can't join my two portions posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT x.bin_type_name,
  x.bin_level floor,
  x.empty_locations EMPTY,
  ( ( b.total total - x.empty_locations ) / y.total total ) * 100  perc_available,
  y.total total,
  TO_CHAR ( sysdate, 'MM-DD-YYYY ' ) AS DAY,
  TO_CHAR ( sysdate, 'hh:mi:ssam' )  AS TIME
   FROM
  (
     SELECT bin_type_name,
      COUNT ( b.bin_id ) empty_locations,
      bin_level
       FROM bins b
    LEFT JOIN bin_items bi
         ON bi.bin_id = b.bin_id
      WHERE quantity IS NULL
      AND USAGE       = '1024'
   GROUP BY bin_type_name,
      bin_level,
      quantity
  )
  x
INNER JOIN
  (
     SELECT bin_type_name,
      bin_level,
      COUNT ( bin_type_name ) AS total
       FROM bins
      WHERE USAGE = '1024'
   GROUP BY bin_type_name,
      bin_level
  )
  y
     ON x.bin_type_name = y.bin_type_name
  AND x.bin_level       = y.bin_level
order by 2  ;
```

Comment: WOW!! Thank you Thank you for taking the time to help out! But, it says I'm missing Right parenthesis on Line 18 column 15?

Comment: Awesome I got it to work! The only thing I changed was trunc(((x.empty_locations)/y.total)*100,2)||'%'  available